# Creating Feeds between local SQL servers and Azure SQL servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are wanting to use Azure servers to run our Power Apps applications, however we have local SQL servers which contains our data warehouse we want only certain tables to be on Azure and want to create data feeds between the two with information going from one to the other.

Does anyone have any insight into how I can achieve this?

I have googled but there doesn't appear to be a wealth of information on this topic.

Comment: Sounds like this is probably what you're after https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how fast after a change in your source (the on premise SQL Server) you need that change reflected in your Sink (Azure SQL).
If you have some minutes or even only need to update it every day I would suggest a basic Data Factory Pipeline (search on google for data factory upsert). Here it depends on your data on how you can achieve this.
If you need it faster or it is impossible to extract an incremental update from your source you would need to either use triggers and write the changes from one database to the other or get a program that does change data capture that does that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to sync the data in some table between local SQL Server and Azure SQL database.

You can use the [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data).

**Summary：**

SQL Data Sync is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you synchronize the data you select bi-directionally across multiple SQL databases and SQL Server instances.

With Data Sync, you can keep data synchronized between your on-premises databases and Azure SQL databases to enable hybrid applications.

A Sync Group has the following properties:

- The Sync Schema describes which data is being synchronized.
- The Sync Direction can be bi-directional or can flow in only one
  direction. That is, the Sync Direction can be Hub to Member, or
  Member to Hub, or both.
- The Sync Interval describes how often synchronization occurs.
- The Conflict Resolution Policy is a group level policy, which can be
  Hub wins or Member wins.

Next step, you need to learn how to configure the Data Sync. Please reference this Azure document:[Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).

In this tutorial, you learn how to set up Azure SQL Data Sync by creating a sync group that contains both Azure SQL Database and SQL Server instances. The sync group is custom configured and synchronizes on the schedule you set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust solution here is [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-to-sql-database).  You can also use SSIS or Azure Data Factory for copying tables to/from Azure SQL Database.  And [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) also exists.